# show g=5 is a generator of p=647 when p is prime

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

How would I show that $g=5$ is a generator of $647$ using [Lagrange’s theorem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory))

So far I have $p-1=646$, thus the $ord<g>$ = $1,2,17,19,646$,

How would I show from here using Lagrange’s theorem that $g=5$ is a generator?

Comment: Process of elimination....

Comment: How does one generate 647?

Comment: General criterion: if $p$ is an odd prime and $a\in\mathbb{F}_p^*$, $a$ is a generator for $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ iff $a^{\frac{p-1}{q}}\not\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ for each prime $q$ dividing $p-1$.

Answer (score 1):

The order of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{647}$, as you note, is $646 = 2 \times 17 \times 19$, so any proper subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^\times_{647}$ must have order in $S = \{2, 17, 19, 34, 38, 323\}$. Check that $5^n \not \equiv 1 \pmod {647}$ for any $n \in S$ (in fact, it suffices just to check $\{34, 38, 323\}$—why?) and you're done.

Comment: hey thanks im not sure but why do we only need to check 34,38 and 323

Comment: If $5^2 \equiv 1$ then $5^{34} = (5^2)^{17} \equiv\, ???$

Comment: but $5^2$≡25mod 647

Comment: To rephrase more explicitly: If $5^n \equiv 1$ then $5^{kn} \equiv 1$ for every integer $k$, so you only need to check the elements of $S$ that don't divide any other element of $S$.